# How to deploy multiple Autofac containers to Owin WebApi2

Tags: asp.net-web-api, owin, autofac

I need to use multiple Autofac containers for different controllers. For example, I have 2 WebApi controllers that should use `container1` as dependency resolver and 3 other WebApi controllers that should use `container2` as dependency resolver. I'm using Owin WebApi2. Can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the problem by registering multiple containers in another container. So, in order to use proper container in proper contoller, I need to manually resolve needed dependencies like this:

```
class SomeController : ApiController
{
    private ISomeDep _dep;

    public SomeController(IComponentContext container)
    {
        // Resolve some dep. from the first container.
        _dep = container.Resolve<IFirstContainer>().Resolve<ISomeDep>();
    }
}
```